# Using PHP to solve an addition and multiplication formula

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now I feel like my head is going to explode trying to figure this out as I'm a beginner in PHP. I'm using wordpress and in my post I'm looping a series of custom fields which will output a number.

```
<?php echo get_post_meta ($card_id, 'card-cost', true); ?>
```

This will then output the numbers from the custom fields so for example lets say the post has 8 of these fields the numbers will show

2
2
3
4
2
5
5
3

What I need is to grab all the same numbers and add them together and set them to a variable

so for 2s we have 3 set so I I would assume something like this

```
$total2 = 2+2+2
$total3 = 3+3
$total4 = 4
$total5 = 5
```

The first thing I'm not sure about is how to execute the loop inside php so instead of printing the above numbers we can store them in php to than add them together.

Once we have them how do we have php pick out just the 2's to add together than just the 3s.

Comment: to get you going on the right track but not hold your hand, you should use array_count_values() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: If you can echo the return value of your function, you can add it to an array as well.

Comment: Put all the numbers inside a collection (table, array, hwatever suits you best), do a loop on each of them, then check if you already passed the number your "on" if not do another loop throught the element and add together all the elements that are the same, else skip the element your "on" in the first loop.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, that may be out of skill level currently as Array's are the one things I've been having trouble working with in php

Comment: @inorganik like you said you could also just do a arraycountvalues() on each value then multipli it by this value.

Comment: You should start with the manual then: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Greenhoe I dont really see how to do this without an array of some sort... unless you want to call a recursive function...

Comment: @Sebastien I was assuming that I needed to use an array, I don't have a complete understanding of them currently which I was hoping to get a little guidance on how to actually write the array for this. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

> try this

```
<?php
    $arr = array(2,4,2,5,8,9,8,9,8,8,8,9,4);
    $aa = array_count_values($arr);
    foreach($aa as $k=>$ar)
    {
        echo ($k * $ar) . '</br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: How would I get the array variables into the $arr = array from wordpress the function I'm using to call the numbers is <?php echo get_post_meta ($card_id, 'card-cost', true); ?>

Comment: /*Creating an array*/ $arr = array(); /*then push value inside*/array_push($arr, $YOURVALUE);

Comment: or Creating and putting value inside at the same time : $ar = array('Key'=>'Value'); /*or*/ $ar = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

Comment: since you are using loop so can use $arr[] = $your_value. define $arr = array(); before loop. hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myNumbers = [2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5, 3];

$results = [];

foreach ($myNumbers as $number){
    $results[$number] = $results[$number] + $number;
}

// $results[2] will be the 2s, etc
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Dont think this is fairly a good answer... let say there is a '49' in there the OPs gonna have to know she got a value in the 49th row of the $results

Comment: @Sebastien What does that matter? You'd have to loop over the results using `foreach` anyway to display the results. The keys will contain the numbers and the values the result.

Comment: Thanks, How would I then store each result in their on variable?

Comment: @jeroen It does matter a bit if you dont use a foreach,

Comment: @Sebastien Note that the resulting array has exactly the same keys as the result of an `array_count_values()` operation.